# aurelia choose between ui components?

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-ui-framework

So I am evaluating Аurelia framework for my next project. I have two major concerns - if it is production ready (or near it) and if there are ui components I can use with it. I have found three things so far:

1. Aurelia interface - not much information about it, no source. As far as I understand it is the official thing developed by the Aurelia team. But it is not much of a use to me, as there as I said there is no source, no examples, nothing;
2. Aurelia materialize bridge: http://aurelia-ui-toolkits.github.io/demo-materialize/#/about - looks fine and there is a npm package about it
3. Aurelia ui framework - http://adarshpastakia.github.io/aurelia-ui-framework/#/home - checked the examples, look good to me but could not find much info about it

I cannot really evaluate between 2 and 3 as there is no much information in the internet or some comparison between the two.

Can someone share some opinion about those based on experience or even suggest some alternatives. Thanks!

Comment: Aurelia Interface  will be a possibility to write Apps with Javascript and have a native look and feel, similiar to Ionic

Comment: I've been using bootstrap classes and features, encapsulating them inside a web components, dealing with necessary javascript just once and reusing it through the application

Comment: That one is no long used the current one is https://github.com/aurelia/ux

Answer (score 3):

1. I suggest you go to the [Aurelia Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/Aurelia) and ask what could be problematic if you go to production with the current version. Core team members are active on the channel.
2. Did you have a look at the [Aurelia Kendo UI Bridge](http://aurelia-ui-toolkits.github.io/demo-kendo/#/catalog-index)? Kendo UI is a pretty complete UI toolkit with free and paid options. The bridge project seem very active and there's a [Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/adriatic/Aurelia-KendoUI) for that project as well.

Comment: Thanks. About point 2 I have used kendo for a project in the past and I do not want to go down this path again.